# Scala import package from subproject

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a subproject that has been imported in the root of my project (root) `domain` is my subproject

The directory structure looks like this:

```
 root
  - modules
    - domain
      - src
       - main
         - scala
           - com.example
             - domain
               - MyClass
```

My `build.sbt` file in the root project contains this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(data, domain).enablePlugins(PlayScala)dependsOn(domain)
lazy val domain = (project in file("modules/domain")).dependsOn(data)
```

I'm trying to state an import in one of my files like this:

`import com.example.domain._`

However, this doesn't seem to be working, as I can't resolve `MyClass` inside the above file.

Comment: where is the `data` module defined?

Comment: How does your `MyClass` looks like?